# PopOS Bootloader not providing option to boot into Windows

Tags: systemd, dual-boot, grub, uefi, pop-os

I have installed Windows on my system's primary nVme drive, and PopOS on the second sata drive on my system, I was hoping to be able to use grub to boot between my Windows and PopOS install (Instead of having to use the bios).

Upon grub-customizer throwing an error and `sudo update-grub` saying `update-grub` doesn't exist, I did a little more research and found [THIS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599472/grub-not-showing-up-in-pop-os).

Apparently PopOS uses systemd-boot instead of Grub by default. So I go to `/boot/efi/loader/loader.conf`, add `timeout 10` on a new line, reboot and there's the menu. The only problem is that with grub I could use `os-prober` to find the Windows drive and make it an option to boot to.

Is there an equivalent I can do to that with systemd-boot?

Comment: This suggests rEFInd works better. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610779/pop-os-systemd-boot-cant-detect-windows & http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908677/want-to-view-contents-of-boot-efi-in-xubuntu-dont-have-permissions
Setting up a multi-boot of 5 Linux distributionsm boot with rEFInd
https://medium.com/@manujarvinen/setting-up-a-multi-boot-of-5-linux-distributions-ca1fcf8d502  and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-boot#Menu_does_not_appear_after_Windows_upgrade